# Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 5.ts(2554)

Tags: angular

I have the following method in my service.ts, however it is always throwing error with Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 5.ts(2554), any idea why?

```
 deleteOneDoc(employeeuuid: String, docuuid: String, contentType: String, cloudinaryId: String) {
    return this.http.put(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/deleteonedoc' + `/${employeeuuid}` + `/${docuuid}` + `/${contentType}` + 
    `/${cloudinaryId}`, employeeuuid, docuuid, contentType, cloudinaryId);
  }
```

Comment: why are you using string templates and string concatenation at the same time?

Comment: `http.put` expects 2-3 arguments, and you are passing 5

Comment: assuming you want to pass those variables through the url AND in an object to the backend (think req.params & req.body) you would need to do http.put(<url>, {employeeuuid, docuuid, contentType, cloudinaryId})

Answer (score 1):

HTTP PUT supports a finite number of parameters. First is the URL for the API endpoint, second the request body (the object holding all the data) and the third the HTTP options which would include headers and tokens. I would refactor to something like this:

```js
export class Document {
    employeeId: string;
    documentId: string;
    contentType: string;
    cloudinaryId: string;
}

deleteDocument(document: Document): Observable<boolean> {
    const formData = new FormData();

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: this.headers
    };

    formData.append('employeeId', document.employeeId);
    formData.append('documentId', document.documentId);
    formData.append('contentType', document.contentType);
    formData.append('cloudinaryId', document.cloudinaryId);

    return this.httpClient.put<boolean>(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/deleteonedoc', formData, httpOptions);
}
```

P.S. Make sure to import all dependencies like `FormData` and `Obeservable`. It is good practice to define what the API will return that's why `Observable<boolean>`. I assumed you return a boolean for success but you can change this to return whatever model you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `http.put()` takes 2-3 variables but you are sending it 5

1. environment.apiBaseUrl + '/deleteonedoc' + `/${employeeuuid}` + `/${docuuid}` + `/${contentType}` +  `/${cloudinaryId}

   2. `employeeuuid`
   3. `docuuid`
   4. `contentType`
   5. `cloudinaryId`

You need to do something like this, because you are already sending in the variables in the service path. you don't need to add them to the end

```
this.http.put(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/deleteonedoc/${employeeuuid}/${docuuid}/${contentType}/${cloudinaryId}`, {observe: 'response'});
```